# Convert string (date) to format D, d M Y

Tags: javascript, date, format

I am trying to transform a date in javascript from the following string:

**Tue Jul 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)**

To:

**Tue, 27 Jul 2021**

I have tried in various ways but I cannot achieve the format I want, if someone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Please show the code where you are seeing this string. Are you sure it's a string and not a `Date` object?

Comment: `'Tue Jul 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)'.substring(0,15).replace(' ',', ')` is pretty close.

Comment: Or there is `let [dayName, month, day, year] = date.split(' '); console.log(\`${dayName}, ${day} ${month} ${year}\`)`. :-)